# DateTimeFormat exception while creating a culture info in C# .Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am getting an exception when I try to initialize `CultureInfo` in my application.

Following is the code I am using:

```
public void SetLanguage(string cultureCode)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureCode))
            {
                _cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en");
            }
            else
            {
                _cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);
            }           
        }
```

I am trying to create culture info for `"no"` culture code but I get exception `PlateformNotSupported` as it can not create `CompareCulture` and `DateTimeFormat` followings are the exceptions:

```
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.Check Neutral(CultureInfo culture)         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_DateTimeFormat()
```

What is missing here , any idea will be appriciated ?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture.aspx) suggests to get a list of supported cultures and try to get required culture from that list. Otherwise use default culture.